# Dismiss "pop-up" modal when keyboard is shown

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom pop-up modal that is triggered by the user. I'd like to dismiss it if the user taps anywhere outside the modal, or if the keyboard is shown. How might I accomplish this?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HelpView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @State var thingIsDisplayed = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        thingIsDisplayed.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Toggle Thing")
                }
                TextField("Something", text: $text)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                if thingIsDisplayed {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 300)
                }
            }
            .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
    }
}

struct HelpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HelpView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Keyboard

You can listen for the `KeyboardWillShow` notification and act on it when it occurs like:

```swift
struct HelpView: View {
// ...
    private let showPublisher = NotificationCenter.Publisher.init(
        center: .default,
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
    )

    var body: some View {
        ZStack { 
            // ...
        }.onReceive(showPublisher) { _ in
            self.thingIsDisplayed = false
        }
```

## 2. Tap Anywhere

Then for the other part you can just add a tap gesture recognizer to the outermost Z Stack like:

```swift
ZStack {}.onTapGesture { 
    if thingIsDisplayed {
        self.thingIsDisplayed = false 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! How might I make `showPublisher` bidirectional so that the keyboard is dismissed when the modal is triggered?

Comment: Nvm, got it working in the other direction with this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield

Comment: if you add the `onTapGesture` to the outermost `ZStack`, the modal will be closed when the user taps on the modal, not "if the user taps anywhere outside the modal"

Comment: the good answer for the `onTapGesture` is the @Duy Trương's one with the `contentShape` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this snippet after first VStack:

```
///...
.padding()
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
    thingIsDisplayed = false
}
```

You may also prevent popup from showing when keyboard is shown by observing `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` notifications.

Answer (score 0):

To perform an action when your keyboard appears / disappears, you must observe `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` :

```
extension Publishers {
    static var keyboardWillShow: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge(
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .map { _ in true },

            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                .map { _ in false }
        )
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

with :

```
.onReceive(Publishers.keyboardWillShow) {
    // action
}
```

to "dismiss it if the user taps anywhere" you can add `onTapGesture` to the first VStack [EDIT : I previously used `Color.white.opacity(0.01)`, but the `.contentShape(Rectangle())` seems better. Thanks to @Duy Trương]:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView6: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var thingIsDisplayed = false

    func showSheet(_ displayed: Bool) {
        guard displayed != thingIsDisplayed else { return }
        withAnimation {
            thingIsDisplayed = displayed
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showSheet(!thingIsDisplayed)
                }) {
                    Text("Toggle Thing")
                }
                TextField("Something", text: $text)
                    .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardWillShow) {
                        showSheet(!$0)
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                showSheet(false)
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                if thingIsDisplayed {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 300)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```